# Edge with alphanumeric label

Tags: orientdb

I am using os x 10.6.8, java 6, and orient 2.0.12. I have noticed the following behavior after executing this code:

```
package orientdb;

import java.io.File;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

public class testEdge {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try{
            File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + "edgeTest");
            if (f.exists())
                f.delete();
            f.mkdirs();
            OrientGraph g = new OrientGraph("plocal:" + f.getAbsolutePath());

            g.begin();
            Vertex v = g.addVertex(null);
            Vertex v1 = g.addVertex(null);
            Edge e = v.addEdge("2k", v1);
            g.commit();
            g.shutdown();
        }
        catch(Exception x){
            x.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I open studio and execute "select from e". The edge label reflected is "-2k" instead of "2k". If the label does not contain digits it does not occur.

Is this a constraint?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is. Edge's label is a OrientDB class that extends `E` (base class for Edges).

Comment: A constraint meaning that labels can not start with digits. It seems that data is being changed. I was expecting "2k" not "-2k"

Comment: So under the hood "2k" becomes a class so the java naming conventions come into play?